# How to assign sequence number when the value entered into nearby cell?

Tags: excel

I want A column to automatically generate sequence number when B column has value inserted.
As my image shows(assign sequence number.jpg), when firstly insert a in B1, it will generate 1 as first insert in A1.
When insert next value b in B5, generate 2 as 2nd insert in A5.
Please help.

I tried IF(B2<>"",MAX($A$1:$A$10)+1,"") but it didn't work.

[assign sequence number.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtdDC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned formula will work. But the only thing here is you have to enter 1 in cell `A1`. Then enter the below formula in `A2`.

```
=IF(B1:B10="","",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,">0")+1)
```

You can change the range according to your requirement. Let me know if this works.